# In Ruby, is there a way to "arr.sort {|i| Math.cos(i) * Math.sin(i)}" instead using |i,j| and repeat it twice?

Tags: ruby

Such as the code:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

irb(main):002:0> a.sort {|d,e| (d - 3).abs <=> (e - 3).abs}
=> [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]    # sort by closest distance away from the number 3
```

it is not so good to repeat the expression twice, and it is too trivial to create a function just for that expression.  Is there also a way to write something like

```
irb(main):002:0> a.sort {|e| (e - 3).abs}  # compare by this expression
```

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the `sort_by` method:

```
a.sort_by {|e| (e - 3).abs}
```

Comment: by the way, the doc says it is slower: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120  "The current implementation of sort_by generates an array of tuples containing the original collection element and the mapped value. This makes sort_by fairly expensive when the keysets are simple"  I tried in Ruby 1.8.6, 1.8.7, and 1.9.2 and they are the same.  I guess it is the generation of new data that makes it slow.

Comment: maybe we can either change `sort` to automatically do that using Metaprogramming (can it detect the block takes only one param?), or create another method to make it as fast as `sort`?

Comment: @動靜能量: It says it's more expensive *if* the sort key is "simple" (though probably not enough to make a practical difference). For expensive calculation, `sort_by` will be faster because each key is only calculated once. There really is no point in trying to optimize unless you know that `sort` is faster for your program and the difference actually matters.